# Where did jsfiddle's run on mobile go?

Tags: jsfiddle

There used to be a little icon I'd press on my jsfiddle and then it'd give me a url where I could point my phone's browser to and see my fiddle running. But they see to have taken it out (?) or maybe I can't find it.

If so, maybe there's another site that you guys know, codepen, jsbin, that does this?

Answer (score 0):

I miss this feature as well and can't find it.

codepen.io allows this, but requires you to sign up for an account (free) and then does so using text messages to send the link to your mobile phone and restricts it to 10 a month.

Not the greatest solution, but it works for intermittent use.